# How does ArrayList index of work?

Tags: java, arraylist

I can not get this Objects out of a ArrayList I think ArrayList uses the equals method and the hashCode method so I do miss something? This is my Object

```
public class OPCode {

public String code;

public OPCode(String code){     

    this.code = code;      
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
 OPCode c = (OPCode) o; 
return this.code.equals(c.code.substring(0, c.code.length()-2)); // returns ture 
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return 1;
}
}
```

and and example

```
ArrayList<OPCode> t_codes = new ArrayList();
 OPCode c = new OPCode("1-202");
    t_codes.add(c);
    OPCode e = new OPCode("1-202.0");
    t_codes.indexOf(e); // -1 <-- Problem here 
    t_codes.indexOf(c) // finds it
```

I want e and c to be equal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The way I see it. You ether need to override equals on OPCode or use a wrapper object that has an overridden equals method

Comment: obviously not a duplicate of how do i compare strings.

Comment: [Beware of how you are using `hashCode()` and `equals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java). Whenever `a.equals(b)`, then `a.hashCode()` must be same as `b.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are wrong. You are breaking the contract.

If I understood well you want to find the index of `e` although there is only `c` in the list, and you want to do so abusing the `String#equals()` checking equality only for the first 5 letters. So `c.code = 1-202`, `e.code = 1-202.0`, doing `c.code.equals(e.code.subString(0, e.code.lenght()-2))` should hold `true`.

This is the correct implementation:

```
public class OPCode {

    public String code;

    public OPCode(String code){     

        this.code = code;      
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((code == null) ? 0 : code.split("\\.")[0].hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        OPCode other = (OPCode) obj;
        if (code == null) {
            if (other.code != null)
                return false;
        } else{
            String thisCode = code.split("\\.")[0];
            String otherCode = other.code.split("\\.")[0];
            if (!thisCode.equals(otherCode))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that I used the method `String#split` since (and this is my assumption) you want to be equal codes with same numerical part without considering decimal part. Using `split` we avoid managing variable number of literals.

Test it with:

```
ArrayList<OPCode> t_codes = new ArrayList<OPCode>();
OPCode c = new OPCode("1-202");
t_codes.add(c);
OPCode e = new OPCode("1-202.0");
System.out.println(t_codes.indexOf(e)); // -1 <-- Problem here now gives 0
System.out.println(t_codes.indexOf(c));
```

BTW I created both method using eclipse built in function via *Source>Generate hashCode() and equals()…* and modified for the task.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the element to the list `t_codes.add(e);`

`t_codes.indexOf(c) // finds it` works because you have added this object to the list `t_codes.add(c);`

But you have not added your object `OPCode e = new OPCode("1-202.0");` to the list. Therefore `t_codes.indexOf(e);` gives you `-1`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer doesn't solve OPs problem. I guess that is why you've got downvoted.

Comment: @Tom Okay, but I think OP was having problem because he forgot to add second object to the list.

Comment: No. He added `c` and he want his program (or the `indexOf` method) to return the index of `c` if he passes `e` to the `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Eclipse. Select the method and press F3 (jdk required). Now you will see implementation:

```
/**
 * Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element
 * in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
 * More formally, returns the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>,
 * or -1 if there is no such index.
 */
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your equals method.

`t_codes.indexOf(c)` is actually referring to `object e`. Because as per your equals method implementation, **e** is equal to **c**, but vice versa is not true.

your `e.equals(c) != c.equals(e)`. You need to revisit equals implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals()` method is not commutative. I.e. `e.equals(c) != c.equals(e)`, so it's not unexpected that you get strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your equals method.

```
return (c.code.equals(code)) || c.code.equals(this.code.substring(0, this.code.length() - 2));
```